# can i call arraylist methods inside other mehods using (this.name of the arraylist method)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods, call

For example, I want to create a method that reverses the order of the arraylist

```
public void  ReverseOrder (){
    this.reversOrder();
    System.out.println(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are trying to do so. Is there any use case for the same?

Anyway if you want to use the field under `ArrayList` object then you need to extend `ArrayList` class on your class and then you will be able to do so with `this`. And if you want to customized `ArrayList`'s methods then you need to override those methods.